# Copy an object to new object with changed value

Tags: powershell, acl, dacl

In need to get the ACL object and replace an `Access.IdentityReference.Value` and keep the rest of the object intact so I can apply the `Set-Acl` to another system.

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Temp"
$h = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
ForEach-Object -InputObject $acl -Process {
    if ($_.Access.IdentityReference.Value -contains "BUILTIN\Users") {
        "found"
        $h += @($_.Access.IdentityReference.Value.Replace("BUILTIN\Users", "new\name"))
    } else {
        $h += @($_)
    }
}
$h.Access
```

I have so many ways to do this and the best I have been able to get is finding and replacing the target value but losing the rest of the original object.

---

**Edit:** when I try this code:

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path 'C:\Temp'

$ace = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -eq 'BUILTIN\Users' }
$newAce = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (
    'new\name',
    $ace.FileSystemRights,
    $ace.InheritanceFlags,
    $ace.PropagationFlags,
    $ace.AccessControlType
)
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)
$acl.AddAccessRule($newAce)

Set-Acl -Path 'C:\Temp' -AclObject $acl
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity
references could not be translated."
At line:12 char:1
+ $acl.AddAccessRule($newAce)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

---

**Edit2:** New script, but not quite there yet:

```
$Ssid = "S-1-5-21-2214593661-3374179426-1523454523-1133"
$Tsid = "S-1-5-21-2227185791-3254421074-497073356-1005"
$Spath = "\\clw01\dept\CLW_Site"
$Tpath = "\\clw03\dept\CLW_Site"

$acl = Get-Acl -Path $Spath

$ace = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -eq $Ssid }
$newAce = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (
    $Tsid,
    $ace.FileSystemRights,
    $ace.InheritanceFlags,
    $ace.PropagationFlags,
    $ace.AccessControlType
)
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)
$acl.AddAccessRule($newAce)

Set-Acl -Path $Tpath -AclObject $acl
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "The trust relationship
between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed."
At line:9 char:1
+ $acl.AddAccessRule($newAce)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SystemException
```

Comment: Is `new\name` actually resolvable on the computer? Is `new` a different host? A trusted domain? External or in the same forest?

Comment: no, it is not resolvable on the computer it is running on, but it would be on the local computer that has the local group. Basically  we have server1 (old server), server2(new server) and AdmWs1(workstation running the script).   Server1 has many folders with local groups permissions to them, I need to copy the folders and local groups to server2, then copy the ACLs

Comment: It must be resolvable on the computer where you're running the code, otherwise it's not going to work. If you want to change a local group on a remote host you may want to run the code remotely, e.g. via `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Or reference the local group by SID?

Comment: You can try, but I'm not sure it'll work.

Comment: I tried the invoke-command and the with a get-acl | set-acl and it still put the sid form the server1 on to server2.. I had hope for that because it translates the sid to the screen.

Comment: See Dave Wyatt's solution here: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/set-acl-on-resource-cross-trusted-forest/

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace the identity reference on an existing ACE, you need to replace the entire ACE with a new one.

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path 'C:\Temp'

$ace = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -eq 'BUILTIN\Users' }
$newAce = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (
    'new\name',
    $ace.FileSystemRights,
    $ace.InheritanceFlags,
    $ace.PropagationFlags,
    $ace.AccessControlType
)
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)
$acl.AddAccessRule($newAce)

Set-Acl -Path 'C:\Temp' -AclObject $acl
```